# Unable to getText from editText

Tags: java, android, xml

```
    public class screen2 extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

            final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);        
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                    //AInteger.parseInt(string)
                    System.out.println("1");
                    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    System.out.println("2");
                    int zipCode =  Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
                    System.out.println("3");
                    System.out.println(zipCode);

                    System.out.println("dude...5");
                 }
            });
        }        
   }
```

This code shows the errror in the logcat :

```
    11-13 19:58:06.806: W/KeyCharacterMap(281): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-13 19:58:09.471: I/System.out(281): 1
11-13 19:58:09.471: I/System.out(281): 2
11-13 19:58:09.477: D/AndroidRuntime(281): Shutting down VM
11-13 19:58:09.477: W/dalvikvm(281): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.example.andtwi.screen2$1.onClick(screen2.java:23)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-13 19:58:09.527: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Though it looks like an Null Pointer exception , i think i am doing it things exactly i found on forums. Here is code of my related xml file as well. Can anyone suggest where am i doing it wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Zipcode" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="5" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get movies from Flixster" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code breaks at this as well :

```
int zipCode =  Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Have you verified that et is not null?

Comment: no.. i have not done that. How can i do that.

Comment: It is solved... i have not much clue for debugger.. will try it though next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post your `onCreate` method, as well as line 23 on its own? The most likely problem is that you neglect to call `setContentView` and that is why `findViewById` returns null.

Comment: Try cleaning your project. In Eclipse choose Project -> Clean

Comment: it worked.. more and more i work on Eclipse... more and more i am getting frustrated.. "clean project stuff + emulator load time".. is it the way Google gonna make Android leading ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out.println("1");                
                System.out.println("2");
                String zipCode = et.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("3");
                System.out.println(zipCode); 
            }
}
```

I think,you don't need to write `String zipCode = (String)et.getText().toString();` there as it is already returns a `String` object.

And hope,you don't miss to include `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file);` before declaring a `Button` and `EditText`.

**Edit 1:**

You don't seem to get problem with

`int zipCode=Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());` there.Try this with above code modification.

You might be getting null pointer exception because you are getting `String s=et.getText().toString()` as null.Please check it for null before casting it to `int`.

Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                System.out.println("1");                
                System.out.println("2");
                String check = et.getText().toString();
                int zipCode=0;
                if(!check.equals(""))
                    zipCode=Integer.parseInt(check);
                System.out.println("3");
                System.out.println(zipCode); 
            }
}
```

Comment: please check the edited code.If you will get 0 printed then your are getting null from your edittext itself.